# Environment variables with dotnet run on mac os using port 80 with kestrel

Tags: macos, environment-variables, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

I'm trying to run an aspnet core application on port 80 on mac os sierra.

There are a few issues:

1. To run on port 80, I need to run `dotnet run` as root.
2. Running as root does not give the application access to the environment variable that I need for it to determine what port to run on, ie `ASPNETCORE_URLS`.

I've tried adding the environment variable to `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile` and then adding this environment key to `sudoers` using `sudo visudoer`.

None of this has given the root user access to the `ASPNETCORE_URLS`. I also have other environment variables that the app needs to read.

So the question: **How can I set environment variables for an app that is running as root?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. I wasn't using as root user. Follow this to enable root user privileges > https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204012